# How can I pass the variables inside loop using this->data[] from controller to view in php CI

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
  $this->data["schedule_count"] = $count;
  $this->data["user_travels" . $i] = $this->travel_order_model->get_travel_schedule($this->data["user_dates"]{$i}->id);
}
```

Error:

> A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

> Message: Undefined variable: user_travels
>
> Filename: travel_order/travel_order_report_summary.php
>
> Line Number: 212

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

> Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
>
> Filename: travel_order/travel_order_report_summary.php
>
> Line Number: 213

Comment: If you are using the data in view then you don't need any ```$this->data[]```. You just have to mention the variable name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
  $this->data["schedule_count"] = $count;
  $this->data["user_travels"][$i] = $this->travel_order_model->get_travel_schedule($this->data["user_dates"][$i]->id);
}
$this->load->view('your_view_file', $data);
```

Your View File, You can print data this way,

```
foreach($user_travels as $travelData){
    print_r($travelData);
}
```

Comment: @user3099298 : I don't think you need ```$this->data``` in the controller while passing to view.

Comment: @Rikesh : You can directly use the variable name
e.g. ```foreach($user_travels as $travelData) { print_r($travelData); }```

Answer (score 1):

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
  $this->data["schedule_count"] = $count;
  // pass Id 
  $this->data["user_travels"][$i] = $this->travel_order_model->get_travel_schedule($this->data["user_dates"][$i]->getId());
}
```